# Can I use an if statement to compare a string parameter in the .ned file- omnet++?

Tags: syntax, omnet++

Can someone help me with the syntax please? I marked the erroneous part
I need to find the correct syntax for if statements in the .ned file of omnet++

```
simple Source
{
    parameters:
        @group(Queueing);
        @signal[created](type="long");
        @statistic[created](title="the number of jobs created"; record=last; interpolationmode=none);
        string jobName = default("job");

        double startTime @unit(s) = default(interArrivalTime); // when the module sends out the first job
        double stopTime @unit(s) = default(-1s); // when the module stops the job generation (-1 means no limit)

        if (jobName =="SimpleEvent"){ //syntax here is wrong!
        volatile int eventType = default(intuniform(1,3));
        }
        gates:
       inout out; //modified
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NED one can use an `if` condition only for connections and submodules. Parameters have to be declared without condition. So in your code should look like:

```
    double startTime @unit(s) = default(interArrivalTime); // when the module sends out the first job
    double stopTime @unit(s) = default(-1s); // when the module stops the job generation (-1 means no limit)      
    volatile int eventType = default(intuniform(1,3));
```

Comment: For connections and submodules!
https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-ref:conditional-submodules